# Path to root in apache (XAMPP)

Tags: apache, xampp, wamp

I need to set up a path to the site root in a config.php file, eg:

```
/htdocs/mysite
/xampp/localhost/mysite
/localhost/htdocs/mysite
```

It doesn't seem to matter what I try it fails to load any files on the path ("failed to open stream: No such file or directory in...").

Do I need something setting in the httpd.conf file for this to work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have mine set like this. In xampp/apache/conf/http.conf:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/drupal/"
```

You could set yours to something like:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/"
```

If I do this, test.php in my drupal folder, running getcwd() returns

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal
```

Comment: Works like a charm, even with junctions for dropbox syncing of sites.